# Most elegant way to make this javascript code DRY

Tags: javascript, dry

Here is a snippet of my JavaScript Code that I want to DRY up:

```
if(agency == 'abcd')map.entities.push(abcd);
if(agency == 'efgh')map.entities.push(efgh);
if(agency == 'xyz')map.entities.push(xyz);
if(agency == 'pqrs') map.entities.push(pqrs);
if(agency == 'values')map.entities.push(values);
```

Now in future may have more ifs for different keys coming in. JavaScript doesnt offer a build in HashMap which i can use here. And using arrays and id stuff to make it DRY is too tacky. 
Is there a more simpler solution to this? May be something like this

```
if(agency == 'abcd')map.entities.push(stringToVariable('abcd'));
```

then I can just use a for and iterate through the keys. I am not sure though this possible at all in JavaScript.

Comment: Are those variables global? Can they be properties of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a legitimate case for using `eval` here as long as you know `agency` values are clean:

```
map.entities.push(eval(agency));
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as writing map.entities.push(window[agency])?

Comment: @Alxandr Only if those variables exist in the global scope.

Comment: The how about `this[agency] || window[gency]`?

Comment: How does this answer the OP's request to push agency if it matches one of five patterns?

Comment: Works perfect in my case. Yes the agency values are clean

Comment: @Rob Raisch: you see this `stringToVariable('abcd')` in the question? was pretty sure eval would win here :) @Shaunak: do not use eval until you are very confident about it :)

Comment: Um. . . you still need to do some other work to DRY this up.  This is not REALLY the solution, rather only a piece.  This is better: `switch(agency) {
    case 'abcd':
    case 'efgh':      
    case 'xyz':
    case 'pqrs':
    case 'values':
        map.entities.push(eval(agency));
}` Strings are legitimate in switch statements in JavaScript.

Answer (score 11):

Well maybe:

```
map.entities.push({abcd: abcd, efgh: efgh, xyz: xyz}[agency]);
```

To me, this is a situation that calls for stepping back and re-thinking more of the situation, as it's just inherently ugly as it stands.  Why are there all these separate variables, instead of a single object with keys corresponding to "agency" values?

Comment: +1 for suggesting the right approach i shoud have taken. Didn't realize as suggested by you and the asnwer below, that every object in JS acts inherently like an hash map. I am still learning the intricacies of JS :)

Answer (score 1):

Every object in javascript IS a hashmap (at least sort of a hashmap), that's why this code returns true:

```
var obj = {};
obj.test = "someVarVal";
obj.test === obj['test'];
```

So, what you can do is build up an object of returnvalues/functions like so:

```
var returns = {};
returns['abcd'] = function() {return 'abcd';};
returns['efgh'] = function() {return 'efgh';};
```

And then do

```
map.entities.push(returns[agency]());
```

If all your variables are statics you can do it even simpler, like so:

```
var returns = {};
returns['abcd'] = 'abcd';
map.entities.push(returns[agency]);
```

Comment: Why assign a function instead of the string?

Comment: Missread on my part, I thought I briefely saw some function in one of them, and thought I'd add that functionality to show how it could be done. Just in case it wasn't all constants. I've updated the answer to show the simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var agency='foo',
    wanted_words=new Regexp(/^abcd|efgh|xyz|pqrs|values$/);

agency.match(wanted_words) && map.entities.push(eval(agency));
```

Assumes all possible values of agency exist as variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
function _inArr(arr,itm)
{
  for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
     if (arr[i] == itm) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var allowedAgencies = array['abcd','efgh','xyz','pqrs','values'];
if (_inArr(allowedAgencies, agency))
{
  map.entities.push(window[agency]);
}
```

The _inArr function is available in every major javascript package ($.inArray, for example).

I think the point is that JavaScript is a big hashmap.  A global function name, for instance, is just a key into the window object.  The same goes for any namespaced items.

Comment: @naveen Not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: otherwise how do you call window[agency]. BTW its my +1 there :)

Comment: Thanks.  I just wasn't sure which you were referring to.  :)